# Data Factory Self-Hosted IntegrationRuntime Inactive Node

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I tries to setup multi nodes on Data Factory v2 self hosted IR, After setting up nodes dispatcher node is up and running but worker node shows inactive status, after restart dmgsvc its active for minute and goes inactive state.Did anyone experience this or know how to fix please advise.

Error: Unable to connect to other integration runtime (self-hosted) nodes. for details please refer blah blah, and the url points to datafactory v1 data management gateway, which is useless.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there are no configurations to hibernate or sleep the vm where you installed the IR. Even if the windows configuration shows that its not going to hibernate or sleep, the company may have group policies, or some configuration on the virtualization HyperV that puts the vm to sleep if its not actively being used.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks Martin for helping.  In my case both are on prem physical computers and are online through out this problem.

Comment: Mmm that's weird. I've had this same problem but I solved it as I suggested, because the vms were being configured to sleep by a group policy. Have you checked if any firewall is blocking the port 443?